# Can we mix MTU values in cluster

Tags: linux, networking, network-interface, hadoop

we have hadoop cluster ( all machines are linux redhat machines version 7.x )

on the VM machines we set MTU=8900 and all other machines we set MTU=9000

we set on VM MTU=8900 because we saw some network problems with MTU=9000

My question:

dose mix of MTU=9000 and MTU=8900 is a problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not mix MTU in the same vlan .

Because the sender expect to have the hability to send a a packet without framentation .

The network reveicer card will will filter out packet with a bigger size , than his local value for MTU .

8900 this is almost the same than 9000 , if you compare to 1500 .

other information  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jumbo_frame